# Convert html/css print media display to .doc with appropriate page breaks?

Tags: html, css, ms-word, file-conversion

I'm looking to export a page that looks good in print media, to word.

Can this be done automatically, or mostly automatically with office apis?

The alternative is to create a program that reads all our style meta data and font meta data and convert to word and force a download.

The issue is our style metadata is already built for css, its a web app after all. And writing my own css parser, doesn't sound like a good use of time.

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds too simple to be true, but I *belive* you can simply rename a ".html" file to ".doc" to force it to open in word, and let office's html rendering take care of the rest.

Comment: The end goal is to use .doc as a library input to another conversion utility for pdf so that its interop for printing. Can you suggest a programatic way to get a doc from what is tantamount to a curl.exe call to a url?

Comment: You want to get from html to pdf, via word?  Why the extra step.  Why no go direct from html to pdf?  Much easier.

Comment: ultimately the user wants both, why not do both.

Answer (score -1):

If it's for reporting purposes, and you think you might have use for more of the same in the future,  you could look at something like reporting services as a way of creating a report that can be downloaded in various formats.  I'm not 100% sure if the newest version allows the creation of .doc files, but you can purchase plugins to permit this.